# how do i addClass to Javascript when class is .signup-container input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the class in jquery and add another class to one of my inputs but I am unsure how to target the class. I am unsure how to target the following class.

I know how to target a single `.class` but I am unsure how to do this when I add input to the class. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

```
.main-signup-container input {
    height: 35px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid  #b3b3b3;
}
```

Comment: On which element do you want to add the class? `input` or `.main-signup-container`?

Comment: I want to add it to the input.

Comment: This is really basic. Just read the documentation on selectors: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: $("#" + errorFields[i]).addClass("inputError");  This is one of my error handlers.  .inputError is asingle class name all on its own. I want to know how to target a class name with an input attached  i.e.  .main-signup-container input {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.addClass` method.

```
$(".main-signup-container input").addClass("someclass");
```

This will add `someclass` on the input element.

**Update:**

Create a new class with styles of `input`

```
.main-signup-container input, .someClass {
    height: 35px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid  #b3b3b3;
}
```

And then add this class to the elements

```
$("#" + errorFields[i]).addClass("inputError");
```

Comment: $("#" + errorFields[i]).addClass("inputError");  errorFields is the array I am using in my for loop. is there any way to replace "inputError" with "main-signup-container input"?

Comment: @Adam so you are trying to add a class on `"#" + errorFields[i]`?

Comment: @Adam and which class do you want to add?

Comment: I want to add "main-signup-container input" in place of "inputError"

Comment: You can not do that, because it is not a class. Do you want to add the styles of the input?

Comment: yes that's it. should I just create a a new class like .newClass and then just add that?

Comment: thanks much. apologies for the slow internet here. I didn't know I could add a class on top of a class like that